# Nightwatch.js - How to goes through multiple links and enter values without duplicating code?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

I am trying to create a tool that enters assessment marks into a system. I currently have it working but the code is very repetitive. I have a JSON file with the student's marks. I then loop through the length of the data and enter the values into the respective inputs. Once I have finished, I submit and go to the next assessment. How can I reduce the amount of duplication?

```
const data = require('data.json')

module.exports = {
  '@tags': ['Assessment'],
  'Enter data for each page'(browser) {
    const courseActionLink =
      '#DataModel_DataLinks_YourAssessments__Data_1__Items_READYTOMARK__Value'
    const submitBtn = '[aria-label="Submit Results"]'
    const nextAssessmentBtn = '[aria-label="Next Assessment"]'
    const alertBtn = '#alert-close'

    for (let d = 0; d < data.length; d++) {
      // Mark Assessment Results
      const personCode = `#DataModel_DataLinks_LearnerAssessments__Data_${d}__Items_RESULT_MARKSOUTOF__Value`
      browser
        .clearValue(personCode)
        .setValue(personCode, data[d].a1total)
        .pause(5000)
    }

    browser
      .click(submitBtn)
      .pause(5000)
      .click(alertBtn)
      .pause(5000)
      .click(nextAssessmentBtn)
      .pause(5000)

    for (let d = 0; d < data.length; d++) {
      // Mark Assessment Results
      const personCode = `#DataModel_DataLinks_LearnerAssessments__Data_${d}__Items_RESULT_MARKSOUTOF__Value`
      browser
        .clearValue(personCode)
        .setValue(personCode, data[d].sbatotal)
        .pause(5000)
    }

    browser
      .click(submitBtn)
      .pause(5000)
      .click(alertBtn)
      .pause(5000)
      .click(nextAssessmentBtn)
      .pause(5000)

    for (let d = 0; d < data.length; d++) {
      // Mark Assessment Results
      const personCode = `#DataModel_DataLinks_LearnerAssessments__Data_${d}__Items_RESULT_MARKSOUTOF__Value`
      browser
        .clearValue(personCode)
        .setValue(personCode, data[d].practicalstotal)
        .pause(5000)
    }

    browser
      .click(submitBtn)
      .pause(5000)
      .click(alertBtn)
      .pause(5000)
      .click(nextAssessmentBtn)
      .pause(5000)

    for (let d = 0; d < data.length; d++) {
      // Mark Assessment Results
      const personCode = `#DataModel_DataLinks_LearnerAssessments__Data_${d}__Items_RESULT_MARKSOUTOF__Value`
      browser
        .clearValue(personCode)
        .setValue(personCode, data[d].a2total)
        .pause(5000)
    }

    browser
      .click(submitBtn)
      .pause(5000)
      .click(alertBtn)
      .pause(5000)
  }
}
```

Comment: First question is how many times will you need to do it?  Is that a static or dynamic number?  If it's a static number then you can try throwing all of that code you already have in a `while` loop.  If the number is dynamic, is there a way to return that number through another method?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 good opportunities for refactoring that I see:

1) Create this function:

```
const clickButtons = function(clickNext) {
  browser
    .click(submitBtn)
    .pause(5000)
    .click(alertBtn)
    .pause(5000)
  if(clickNext) {
    browser
      .click(nextAssessmentBtn)
      .pause(5000)
  }
}
```

Obviously you can name it whatever you like. Then you can replace those click-and-pause blocks of code with `clickButtons(true)`, except the very last one, which would be `clickButtons(false)`.

2) The only difference in those for loops is which member you are taking from `data[d]`. You can parameterize that easily, too, by referencing that member as a string:

```
const markAssessment = function(memberName) { 
  for (let d = 0; d < data.length; d++) {
    // Mark Assessment Results
    const personCode = `#DataModel_DataLinks_LearnerAssessments__Data_${d}__Items_RESULT_MARKSOUTOF__Value`
    browser
      .clearValue(personCode)
      .setValue(personCode, data[d][memberName])
      .pause(5000)
  }
}
```

With both of those, your code would then look like

```
markAssessment('a1total')
clickButtons(true)
markAssessment('sbatotal')
clickButtons(true)
markAssessment('practicalstotal')
clickButtons(true)
markAssessment('a2total')
clickButtons(false)
```

You could also put a call to `clickButtons` inside `markAssessment`, adding `clickNext` as a 2nd arg to `markAssessment`. From there, you could store the  memberNames in an array and use `memberNameArray.forEach` to do most of the heavy lifting for you, depending on your needs, but that's only getting rid of a few extra lines at this point.